# Round in SQL creating extra decimals for some rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using a round statement to limit a column to two decimal places. The query works but several cells in the output are not rounded. It appears that every one of of the "broken"  cells has an output very close to rounding up, such as "12.919999999999998" or "14.669999999999998." Does anyone know what causes this? Code below. Thanks.

```
SELECT
order_name, 
ROUND((bid_price_usd / winning_price_usd),2) AS ratio, 
COUNT(*) 
FROM schema.table
GROUP BY 1, 2
HAVING COUNT(*)  >= 10000
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Comment: Instead of using ROUND, why don't you use CONVERT(DECIMAL(precision,scale), value) to get more predictable output?

Comment: @AaronBertrand, nice recommendation. Could you add that comment as an answer so that Mark can accept it and put closure to the question?